# Hide a div if another div with contains string

Tags: jquery

i have the following

```
<dd class="variation-">
    <p>Gift Product</p>
</dd>
```

and i want to hide another `div` with name `popupDiv` to be hidden if it finds the word in the `div` above.

Comment: Please show us what you already have tried. When should the `popupDiv` be hidden? On `document.ready`? On any click? Please be more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. But why you want it is anyones guess.

```
if ($(".variation").html().indexOf("div") != 0 ){
    $("div[name=popupDiv]").hide()
}
```